# Get all documents from collection with realtime in FireStore web

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm trying to get all the elements from a collection in **real-time**.

I don't know if this is possible since I couldn't find any documentation about it. I know it's possible to get everything from a collection, but I'm not sure if you can do it in real-time.

I have the following code that only works once when I load the page:

```js
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users"));
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}`);
});
```

Do you know if there is a way to do the same but in real-time with "`onSnapshot`"?
I'm using *Next 13* if it helps or gives you more context.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by _"in real-time"_. When you call `getDocs()`, it will return the current state of the collection. Is that not _"real-time"_?

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. I mean, get updates in real time after that first request.

Comment: What I'm trying is to get everything from a collection. I could be wrong, but what you say, only works for a single document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Get realtime updates with Cloud Firestore - Listen to multiple documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection). You'll want to use `onSnapshot()` to create a subscription.

You can pass any query or doc reference to `onSnapshot()`, including an unqualified collection reference.

> The snapshot handler will receive a new query snapshot every time the query results change (that is, when a document is added, removed, or modified).

In a React context, this is best done in an effect hook where you can call the returned [*unsubscribe* function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener) during [cleanup](https://react.dev/learn/lifecycle-of-reactive-effects#the-lifecycle-of-an-effect).

For example

```js
useEffect(
  () =>
    onSnapshot(collection(db, "users"), (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
      });
    }),
  []
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Given below is a Hook that I have written in order to accomplish this. It listens to updates to the database and returns the complete list of documents of the collection that is passed,

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { projectFirestore } from '../firebase/config';
import { collection, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";

const useFirestore = (coll) => {
    const [docs, setDocs] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribed = onSnapshot(collection(projectFirestore, coll), (snapshot) => {
            const documents = snapshot.docs
                .sort((a, b) => b.data().createdAt - a.data().createdAt)
                .map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }));

            setDocs(documents);
        });

        return () => unsubscribed();
    }, []);

    return {docs};
}

export default useFirestore;
```

`projectFirestore` is the instance of the SDK for interacting with Firestore. I believe it is typically convention to call this `db`.

Given below is an example of using this function to populate an image grid component,

```
import React from "react";
import useFirestore from "../hooks/useFirestore";

const ImageGrid = () => {
    const {docs} = useFirestore("images");

    return (
        <div className="img-grid">
            {docs && docs.map((doc) => (
                <div className="img-wrap" key={doc.id}>
                    <img src={doc.url} alt="uploaded pic"/>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default ImageGrid;
```